# Interpreter Pattern example

Tags: design-patterns, interpreter-pattern

I am curious to know a few real time examples of interpreter pattern. I am able to find a few repeated examples such as the "regular expression" example. Can anyone direct me towards other examples?

Comment: You mean, besides the ones described in "Design Patterns" [GoF] ?

Comment: Yes other than the ones described in gof.Any scenarios one can think of where the pattern fits well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any mechanism for interpreting formal languages suites this pattern perfectly, it can be **anything**: from a simple calculator to a C# parser.

A lot of software includes command-line input from the user: so named command - shell. Think of different math packages or AutoCAD command input possibilities, basically kind of input that has to be parsed and has a certain level of complexity. Really a lot of complex systems should possess benefit from some formal rules enforced through formal languages

Comment: So..Could text to speech applications be considered as a real time implementation of this pattern?

Comment: It depends on the task and used algorithms behind it. If you do text recognition, then yes. Formal grammars is the keyword and if you want to know more read Aho's book on compilers. PS: accepted answer without an upvote is strange)

Comment: I dont have enough reps to vote yet..I am a newbie at stackoverflow..thanks for your answer..

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the dofactory [sample with roman numbers](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternInterpreter.aspx)? It looks quite straight-forward to me.

Another perhaps more comprehensive example might be [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/InterpreterPatternCalculator.htm) calculator.

Comment: The java2s example link below the calculator example "to search a contact list" was a good example...thanks